# Batch File Error When Setting CLASSPATH

Tags: java, batch-file, weka

I have a number of weka datasets I need to run at once so I was creating a batch file to do that.

```
@ECHO OFF

FOR /r %%I IN (*.arff) DO (
    ECHO Running %%~nI
    SET CLASSPATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Weka-3-6\weka.jar
    java weka.classifiers.functions.LinearRegression -t %%~nI -x 10
)
```

When I run the SET CLASSPATH command and the java command in a regular command line they work fine, and they also work on their own in a batch file but as soon as I nested them in a for loop, I started getting "\Weka-2-6\weka.jar was unexpected at this time" errors.

I'm not an expert in Java or in Batch file programming so forgive me if the fix is really simple but I've been up and down the internet and I haven't found any solutions to this problem. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have u tried enclosing the path in double quotes as SET CLASSPATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\Weka-3-6\weka.jar"

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the error persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal
SET "CLASSPATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\Weka-3-6\weka.jar""

FOR /r %%I IN (*.arff) DO (
    ECHO Running %%~nI
    java weka.classifiers.functions.LinearRegression -t %%~nI -x 10
)
endlcoal
```

set class path can be expanded after the for loop is finished.So better defined it outside the loop.

Comment: The quotes are a good idea to prevent inadvertent trailing spaces from being included in the value. But the SET command does not stop at the first space of an unquoted value. Also, the SET value does take effect immediately, you just can't see it with normal expansion. Delayed expansion would expose the newly set value within the loop. Moving the SET before the start of the loop is the best option.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I didn't see that; it makes a lot of sense.